# How to make describe-function "C-h f" case-insensitive by default

Tags: emacs, case-insensitive

When searching for a function whose name I partly remember, I use <kbd>C-h f</kbd> to call `describe-function`, enter `*part-of-function-name`, and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>. But I now realize that this search is not case-insensitive.

For example:

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `info` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

lists all functions starting with `info`, but doesn't include those starting with `Info`, whereas

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `Info` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

lists all functions starting with `Info`, but doesn't include those starting with `info`.

Another example:

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `*nfc` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

gives me `*nfc [No match]`, whereas

<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `*NFC` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

gives me `ucs-normalize-HFS-NFC-region`.

How can I make `describe-function` case-insensitive by default, using some configuration in my `init.el` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(setq completion-ignore-case t)` should do what you want, tho globally rather than only for `C-h f`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a binding of `completion-ignore-case` to `t` in the `interactive` spec of the command. This has the advantages that (a) it affects only `describe-function` (`C-h f`) and (b) you can easily toggle it on/off (as with any Emacs advice).

```
(defadvice describe-function (before ignore-case activate)
  "Make it case-insensitive."
  (interactive
   (let ((completion-ignore-case       t) ; <============= ADDED BINDING
         (fn                           (function-called-at-point))
         (enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
         val)
     (setq val  (completing-read
                 (if fn
                     (format "Describe function (default %s): " fn)
                   "Describe function: ")
                 obarray 'fboundp t nil nil (and fn  (symbol-name fn))))
     (list (if (equal val "") fn (intern val))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom function that I use in place of `describe-function`.
It uses ido completion.

```lisp
(defvar functions-cache nil)
;;;###autoload
(defun refresh-functions-cache ()
  (interactive)
  (setq functions-cache nil)
  (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
              (when (fboundp symbol)
                (push (symbol-name symbol) functions-cache))))
  (setq functions-cache (sort functions-cache #'string<)))

;;;###autoload
(defun describe-function-ex (function)
  "Display the full documentation of FUNCTION (a symbol)."
  (interactive
   (let ((fn (function-called-at-point))
         (enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
         val)
     (unless functions-cache
       (refresh-functions-cache))
     (setq val (ido-completing-read
                (if fn
                    (format "Describe function (default %s): " fn)
                  "Describe function: ")
                functions-cache
                nil t nil nil
                (and fn (symbol-name fn))))
     (list (if (equal val "")
               fn (intern val)))))
  (if (null function)
      (message "You didn't specify a function")
    (help-setup-xref (list #'describe-function function)
                     (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
    (save-excursion
      (with-help-window (help-buffer)
        (prin1 function)
        (princ " is ")
        (describe-function-1 function)
        (with-current-buffer standard-output
          ;; Return the text we displayed.
          (buffer-string))))))
```